# Test web service on GlassFish or Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, testing, glassfish-3

I need to do some performance tests of my web service, in fact it is a simple servlet. I'm using GlassFish 3.1 but i can switch to Tomcat. Could you give some advices and tools names which i can use to do these tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the open source jmeter tool quite a lot. Here is the project page: http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more question. Some windows tools maybe? : P

// EDIT
Soz, it's for Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) as the best tool for testing SOAP web services.

If it's a REST service, you can use any client that can make an HTTP request to a URL.  You can use [java.net.URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) to do that.

I don't see how GLASSFISH or Tomcat matter here.  Both have compliant servlet engines.

Comment: Well... I prefer REST. Do you recommend any specyfic tool?